# Unable to dismiss intent activity in libgdx

Tags: android, android-intent, libgdx

I have developed a game on `libgdx` in which I am trying to share text content using `Intent`. The   intent activity is shown when I click on share button in my game. The problem is that the activity keeps popping up even when i click back button. I am unable to dismiss the activity and go back to my game screen.The android code is below,

```
public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication implements AndroidIntent{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.useGL20 = true;
        cfg.useAccelerometer = true;
        cfg.useCompass = false;

        initialize(new MyGame(this), cfg);
    }

    @Override
    public void share() {
        Log.d("magicwords", "Sharing the game");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "this is the status line");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share using"));

    }
}
```

`AndroidIntent` is my interface which has `share()`.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the problem.It is due to touchlistener. For single touch interfaces such as options and menus, one should use **Gdx.input.justTouched()**. If you need touch and drag feauture, use **Gdx.input.isTouched()**. Since I used **isTouched()**, the multiple calls to intent activity was sent. Posted the code here for others to lookup.

```
    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0.0f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    camera.update();

    // coordinate system specified by the camera.
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(...);
    batch.end();

            //for single touch down
    if(Gdx.input.justTouched())
    {
        processTouch((int)touchPos.x, (int)touchPos.y);
    }

            //for continuous touch(drag)
    if(Gdx.input.isTouched())
    {
        processTouch((int)touchPos.x, (int)touchPos.y);
    }
}
```